# AngularJS: Updating a view with a template from a controller?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have been working with routing and I have seen how I can update the ng-view using routing and a view template..  But the problem I have is that I am doing a REST call and depending what I get back from the response I wish to update part of the DOM with a view template but I don't want to involve routing.

Does anyone know how I can do this? Or any examples would be great

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hang on.. You mention that you do not want routing so my answer below is invalid - why do you don't want routing?

Comment: I was looking for an alternative, in the jquery days I couldn't just replace the content of an ID in the DOM with a template. If I have to use routing then fine but I wasn't wanting to change the route just to update the display saying that was an error from the service for example

Comment: In case of an error, you can display the error in the same view that you currently are in, couldn't you? Only in case of a success you could change the route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer. Based on your description in the comment, it sounds like you wish to display part of the DOM conditionally.

When you want to display part of the DOM conditionally, you have the following choices:

**Use an `ng-show` and `ng-hide` directive.**
Based on what returns from the RESTful call, you can set up a model that will identify the DOM that needs to be displayed. An example:

```
<div ng-show="status">
    This text will be shown only when the status is truthy
</div>
<div ng-hide="status">
    This text will be shown only when the status is false.
</div>
```

Inside your controller, you could then set the `status` to true or false based on your RESTful calls and based on which part of the DOM you wish to display post RESTful call.

**You can use `ng-switch` directive**
While the `ng-show` and `ng-hide` directives will display the content of your DOM conditionally, that is anybody could simply open the source file and see the contents for both, `ng-switch` directive will load the contents only based on which case fulfills the swtich. An example:

```
<div ng-switch on="status">
    <div ng-switch-when="true">
        This text will be shown only when the status is truthy.
        Else this is completely hidden and cannot be seen even 
        when looking at the source.
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-when="false">
        This text will be shown only when the status is false.
        Else this is completely hidden and cannot be seen even 
        when looking at the source.
    </div>
</div>
```

The first child div is shown when the status is true else it is not shown at all. The advantage over `ng-show` or `ng-hide` is that the DOM will not contain the child elements if the case is not fulfilled.

Answer (score 0):

`$location.path()` can be used here.

So, in your Parent Controller, you can make the REST call. Once you have the data with you, you can then decide which route to take. The route value goes into the `path()` function.

As an example, let us say that if your REST call returns with cherries, you need to take the `/foo` path (which, based on your `$routeProvider` will load the template associated with that route). You can then write the following:

```
$location.path('/foo');
```

and it will loads the /foo path - `$routeProvider` will then take care of loading the template associated with that path.

Reference: [$location](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location#path)